# Любоваться кем/чем или на кого/что?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В толковом словаре, а также в справочнике Розенталя "Глагольное управление", **вторая форма дана в качестве разговорной**, но при этом в Нацкорпусе она встречается часто.

Розенталь указывает **на стилевое различие форм, но, может быть, они имеют и смысловое различие?** Всегда ли одна форма может заменить другую, или возможны случаи, когда подходит только одна? Если такое различие существует, то на чем оно основано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для меня вторая форма выглядит почти так же странно и *по-одесски*, как напр. "*восхищаться на...*". Поэтому если где-то в разговоре она и заменяет обычную (в нарочито политкорректном варианте разговорного "пялиться на..." - где при всей просторечности глагола управление правильное), то это из области "**не всегда**" и, по всей вероятности, "не везде". Видимо, речь идёт об очень узком круге терпимых когда-то выражений вроде "*любоваться на закат*" или на что-нибудь ещё в прямой видимости и в прямом же смысле. Могу представить себе такое только в речи персонажей старых литературных произведений.

Comment: Но в Нацкорпусе 136 примеров с предлогом НА, и они совсем не похожи на разговорную речь. А вот в таком предложение тоже Т.п. предпочтительнее: "Так было приятно после пережитой опасности торжествовать победу, любоваться на поверженных врагов...".

Comment: Нет, не предпочтительнее. Тем не менее это именно разговорная речь. Говоря без затей и не цитируя толковые словари, скажем так: любоваться можно чем-то хорошим. Верно? А не "поверженным плохим". Вернее, можно и поверженным плохим, но это будет именно разговорный стиль. Примерно то же самое: "Полюбуйтесь-ка на нее!" Творительный здесь тоже не допускается.

Comment: Из словаря: ЛЮБОВАТЬСЯ, Рассматривать кого-, что-л. с восхищением, удовольствием.  Но можно же сказать: СМОТРЕТЬ на кого-, что-л.с восхищением, удовольствием.  Здесь глагольное управление с использованием предлога НА ,  поэтому он используется и с глаголом "любоваться". Кстати,  словаре Ушакова  форма с предлогом НА допускается http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Ushakov-term-27687.htm

Comment: "Смотреть с удовольствием" можно, но глагол "любоваться" выражает не столько само действие разглядывания, сколько восприятие результата этого действия (получение удовольствия). Видимо, это смещение акцента отражается на управлении - по смыслу это тяготеет к "восхищаться наблюдаемым".

Comment: Словарь Ушакова ценен уже только в историческом плане. Вот был такой словарь, который отражал состояние языка тогда-то и тогда-то.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже считаю, что предлог "на" после глагола "любоваться" уместен, скорее, в случаях с негативной оценкой ситуации, как в побудительных выражениях типа "Вы только полюбуйтесь на _!" В остальных случаях он выглядит  малограмотно.